# XMLHttpRequest.status doesn't return a value

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm in the midst of trying to use javascript to parse an XML document, and keep running into the following problem:

When I attempt to use xmlhttp.status to check whether or not the file I'm trying to fetch exists, I get a "Access to restricted URI denied" error whenever the file I'm trying to fetch doesn't exist.

To illustrate, when run the following code, I get the aforementioned error.

```
function loadXML(input_url) {
    var xmlDoc;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",input_url,false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {        //File exists
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        return xmlDoc
    }
    else if (xmlhttp.status == 404) {   //File doesn't exist
        alert("Hey! The file doesn't exist!");
        return;
    }

    var url = prompt("Please enter a URL here: :");
    var XMLDoc = loadXML(url);
```

So when I run the above code with a valid url, everything is fine and dandy.

However, its only when I try to access an invalid url (where the file doesn't exist) that I run into the aforementioned problem.

I've looked at other responses and I'v actually made some progress using try/catch expressions.

However, for the life of me I can't figure out why entering the else if block generates this error. Any advice/direction on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it asynchronously.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
        if(xmlhttp.status === 200)
            /* do stuff */
        else
           /* do other stuff */
     } else 
         console.info("state is " + req.readyState);
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", input_url, true); // note the true parameter for async
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

The `console.info` will let you know if the request is "blocked" in a state, but it should never be the case even if the url is invalid or stuff, you should always end up in the 4th step.

Try this and let me know.

Also, make sure to read https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest, as there seems to be limitation on max concurrent requests by default, etc.